# Drawing a buffer zone on a specified point in R

Tags: r, openstreetmap, buffer

I want to draw three buffer with 400mt, 800mt and 1200mt on specified map utilizing Open Street Map in R.

```
library(OpenStreetMap)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
lat1 <- 41.245; lat2 <- 41.26; lon1 <-32.685 ; lon2 <-32.67
pointLong=32.675;pointLat=41.25;
ConvertMet2Latcoords<-function(metre){
  # Latitude: 1 deg = 110.574 km
  OneMetre=(1/110.574)/1000
  OneMetre*metre
}
sa_map <- openmap(c(lat1, lon1), c(lat2, lon2), type = "osm", mergeTiles = TRUE)
sa_map2 <- openproj(sa_map)
OpenStreetMap::autoplot.OpenStreetMap(sa_map2) +
  geom_point(x=pointLong,y=pointLat,shape="\u2297", size = 3 )+
  geom_point(x=pointLong,y=41.2535973,shape=21,fill="blue" , size = 3)+ # 400 metre https://www.calculator.net/distance-calculator.html?type=3&la1=41.25&lo1=32.675&la2=41.253602&lo2=32.675&ctype=dec&lad1=38&lam1=53&las1=51.36&lau1=n&lod1=77&lom1=2&los1=11.76&lou1=w&lad2=39&lam2=56&las2=58.56&lau2=n&lod2=75&lom2=9&los2=1.08&lou2=w&x=76&y=12#latlog
  geom_point(x=pointLong,y=41.25719457, fill="blue", size = 3)+ #800 metre https://www.calculator.net/distance-calculator.html?type=3&la1=41.25&lo1=32.675&la2=41.257203&lo2=32.675&ctype=dec&lad1=38&lam1=53&las1=51.36&lau1=n&lod1=77&lom1=2&los1=11.76&lou1=w&lad2=39&lam2=56&las2=58.56&lau2=n&lod2=75&lom2=9&los2=1.08&lou2=w&x=0&y=0#latlog
  geom_point(x=32.684,y=41.2584,shape=21, fill="red", size = 3 )+  # 1200 metre https://www.calculator.net/distance-calculator.html?type=3&la1=41.25&lo1=32.675&la2=41.2584&lo2=32.684&ctype=dec&lad1=38&lam1=53&las1=51.36&lau1=n&lod1=77&lom1=2&los1=11.76&lou1=w&lad2=39&lam2=56&las2=58.56&lau2=n&lod2=75&lom2=9&los2=1.08&lou2=w&x=0&y=0#latlog

  geom_circle(aes(x0 = pointLong, y0 = pointLat, r = ConvertMet2Latcoords(400) ), inherit.aes = F)+
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = pointLong, y0 = pointLat, r = ConvertMet2Latcoords(800) ), inherit.aes = F)+
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = pointLong, y0 = pointLat, r = ConvertMet2Latcoords(1200) ), inherit.aes = F)+
  xlab("") + ylab("")+ theme_bw()
```

There is a problem in this regard: The circles are not accurate because of Longitude. The red point distance is 1200mt, but it is not on the circular buffer. I need a buffer which presents geographic realities.

[image]

Comment: Why not to use `sf::st_buffer()` function for buffer creation?

Comment: Using a fixed conversion factor in circle construction makes "circles" that aren't circles. If the basemap is Web Mercator or geographic, the "circles" should *not* be circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vince said, there will be a missmatch using just cicles from ggplot when using maps.  You will need to use a projection to show those smooth and simetric circles. Otherwise you can try this (with a few changes over your code):

```
  library(OpenStreetMap)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggforce)
  library(sf)
  points<-data.frame(v1=c("p0","p1","p2","p4"),
                     X=c(32.675,32.675,32.675,32.684),
                     Y=c(41.25,41.2535973,41.25719457,41.2584)
  )
  
  colnames(points) <- c("NAME", "X", "Y")
  
  
  # Create points and buffers
  ps <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("X", "Y"), remove = FALSE, crs="EPSG:4326")
  ps$X <- as.numeric(ps$X); ps$Y <- as.numeric(ps$Y)
  blist <- c(400, 800, 1200)
  bufs <- lapply(seq_along(blist), function(x) st_buffer(ps[1,], blist[x]))
  bufs <- do.call(rbind, bufs)
  
  # Config your view
  lat1 <- 41.245; lat2 <- 41.26; lon1 <-32.685 ; lon2 <-32.67
  
  sa_map <- openmap(c(lat1, lon1), c(lat2, lon2), type = "osm", mergeTiles = TRUE)
  sa_map2 <- openproj(sa_map)
  
  map <- OpenStreetMap::autoplot.OpenStreetMap(sa_map2)+
    geom_sf(ps[1,], mapping = aes(X,Y), shape="\u2297", size = 3)+
    geom_sf(ps[2,], mapping = aes(X,Y), shape=21, fill="blue" , size = 3)+
    geom_sf(ps[3,], mapping = aes(X,Y), fill="blue", size = 3)+
    geom_sf(ps[4,], mapping = aes(X,Y), shape=21, fill="red", size = 3 )+
    xlab("") + ylab("")+ theme_bw()
  
  map
  
  # add buffers
  map <- map + geom_sf(bufs, mapping = aes(X,Y), fill="transparent")
  map
  
  # clip layout
  map+coord_sf(xlim = c(lon1, lon2), ylim = c(lat1, lat2), expand=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @César_Arquero  . Unfortunately this is not working.  I added library(sf) to codes also.
I found ps variable is not defined properly.

> ps
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 3 fields

Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 2 ymax: 4
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
  NAME X Y    geometry
1   P0 1 1 POINT (1 1)
2   P1 1 2 POINT (1 2)
3   P2 1 3 POINT (1 3)
4   P4 2 4 POINT (2 4)

Comment: Are you sure that you are coping exactly the code ? I've just tested it with a clean workspace and it worked...

Comment: Unfortunately, these codes are not working. Can anybody else run this code please?